# How to avoid user inputs from going over, using two scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm new to c, and I'm not sure how to word this question. But for example using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x,y,z;

    printf("Enter 2 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    printf("Test: ");
    scanf("%d",&z);

    printf("x:%d y:%d z:%d\n",x,y,z);

    return 0;
}
```

If the user inputs "1 2 3", it would set x=1, y=2 and z=3. I was wondering if you could set x=1 and y=2 and ignore 3, then the user can input another value and not use the 3 given before.

Comment: You can flush the input after the first scanf. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c).

Comment: You can use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) (or POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) to read a line and then scan it with [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) instead of `scanf()`.  This is often a better way to process data; it allows you to report errors better, and allows you to try alternative ways of scanning the data if the first format doesn't work.

Comment: Totally agree with @JonathanLeffler: You should use `fgets()` to get one line, then `sscanf()` to process it carefully (checking the return values from those functions, of course).

Comment: Well you may want to use

    scanf("%d",&z);
    scanf("%d",&z);

that is, scan the value two times. The first one will be overwritten

This is not the obvious solution but it may help

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int x,y,z;
    char s[1024];

    printf("Enter 2 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    fgets(s, 1024, stdin);

    printf("Test: ");
    scanf("%d",&z);

    printf("x:%d y:%d z:%d\n",x,y,z);

    return 0;
}
```

It initializes a string pointer with `1024 bytes` and after reading the first two integers ignore the remaining content on that line, then prompts `Test:` and reads `z` variable.

**EDIT** Use code below as I tested it with line of `0 <= lentgh <= 8.1k characaters`!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int x,y,z;
    char ch;

    printf("Enter 2 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    while(scanf("%c", &ch)) if(ch == '\n') break;

    printf("Test: ");
    scanf("%d",&z);

    printf("x:%d y:%d z:%d\n",x,y,z);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never use `gets()`.  Never, never, never!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, give me an alternative `:)`.

Comment: See [Why `gets()` is so dangerous it should not be used — ever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) for a list of alternatives.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, updated the answer with `fgets()` `:)`.

Comment: So now we have a memory leak instead?  Use `char s[1024];` instead.

Comment: What happens if the user enters a 2,000 character line?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, what if user enters a 10,000 characters line?!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I don't know why I didn't use that the first time! good reminder.

Comment: @MaskedMan *what if user enters a 10,000 characters line?!* Your code doesn't work.  That's what happens.

Comment: 10000 char line?  use a `while()` loop, where the call to `fgets()` controls the `while()` loop  I.E.  `while( fgets( s, sizeof(s), stdin ); );`

Comment: @AndrewHenle it does not have line limitation anymore `:)`.